# Site stats not loading for Chinese site

Tags: bug, status-norepro, statistics

The site stats are not showing on [Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/), but they are for other sites.

I can't see a dead AJAX call in Firebug.

It says Loading...

Comment: looks fine to me. Probably just a temporary caching issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with our caching layer and a few APIs at the moment, working on it now - all oddities like this should be resolved shortly.